# uitextview can not display selection or cursor after hide the keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview, selection

The UiTextView can display selection or cursor when the keyboard is showing. 
i want to hide the keyboard and keep the UiTextView displaying the selection or cursor(i am showing a format setting panel below the UiTextView, and want to modify the format of selection of textview through the format panel, so keeping selection of textview displaying in need).

thanks~

Comment: can u elaborate more ur question.....?

Comment: the textView is editable.  the soft keyboard shows when click the textView,  and the textView can  display selection and cursor. The keyboard dismisses when "textview resignFirstResponder" is called,  the textview ends editing mode  and stop displaying selection or cursor, but what i need is that textview still displays selection or cursor after the keyboard dismiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to hide keyboard only not cursor  . Try following code :

```
for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES) {

                keyboard.alpha = 0;// here change keyboard alpha
            }
        }
}
```

**Swift & IOS 10**

```
    let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows for window in windows { 
      if (NSStringFromClass(window.classForCoder) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow") { 
        let subViews = window.subviews if (subViews.count > 0) { subViews[0].alpha = 0 
      } 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but "if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)"  doesn't work in iOS 10.2.  then i try code below :let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
  for window in windows {
   if (NSStringFromClass(window.classForCoder) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow") {
    let subViews = window.subviews
    if (subViews.count > 0) {
     subViews[0].alpha = 0
    }
   }
  }

Comment: let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
  for window in windows {
   if (**NSStringFromClass(window.classForCoder) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"**) {
    let subViews = window.subviews
    if (subViews.count > 0) {
     subViews[0].alpha = 0
    }
   }
  }-------------------- this does work! Thanks very much.

Comment: working in iOS 10.2.  Any problem??   Accepted answer.